# WP function and shortcode not firing every time

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm having an issue trying to run a top custom admin bar. So basically when someone is logged out they receive "Log In". When logged in they receive protected links. The issue is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It's not an issue of every other time, but just at random times. Sometimes on phone and sometimes on desktop. I can't find any consistency to determine the issue. My question is, has anyone seen this occurring before? Is there something I can do as far as priority? This is located in the header file if that points to any issues.

> Functions.php

```
function personal_message_when_logged_in() {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
        $is_admin = "<a href='" . esc_url( home_url( 'wp-admin' ) ) . "'>| Admin</a>";
    }else 
    $is_admin = "";
    echo '<li class="firstSpaceInline legacySansBold loggedTab"><span class="welcomeMessage">Hi, ' . $current_user->user_nicename . '! |  <a href="' . esc_url( home_url( 'my-menu' ) ) . '">My Menu<em></em></a></span> </li><li class="logOut"><span><a href="' . wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) . '">Log Out</a> '.$is_admin.'</span></li>';

    else :
        echo '<li class="logInlink"><a href="' . esc_url( home_url( 'bv-login' ) ) . '"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> <span class="glyphicon-lock-text">Log In</span></a></li>';

    endif;
}//if user logged
add_shortcode('personal_message_when_logged_in', 'personal_message_when_logged_in');
```

> header.php

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[personal_message_when_logged_in]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of issues at play here but the main change you need to make is to return content instead of outputting it directly.

```
function personal_message_when_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $admin        = '';

        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
            $admin = "<a href='" . admin_url() . "'>| Admin</a>";
        }

        $output = '<li class="firstSpaceInline legacySansBold loggedTab"><span class="welcomeMessage">Hi, ' . $current_user->user_nicename . '! |  <a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/my-menu' ) ) . '">My Menu<em></em></a></span> </li><li class="logOut"><span><a href="' . wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) . '">Log Out</a> ' . $admin . '</span></li>';

    } else {
        $output = '<li class="logInlink"><a href="' . esc_url( home_url( '/bv-login' ) ) . '"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> <span class="glyphicon-lock-text">Log In</span></a></li>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```